# Onlyoffice shows file access error when I try to save new document to my desktop (Windows 10)

Tags: permissions, save, onlyoffice

I have a problem with Onlyoffice showing an error when I try to save any document.
The issue says that the file I try to save is **already accessed by another program**, I have **no permissions to the folder** or there's **no space on my drive**. The document is new, just getting created now via Onlyoffice so it can't be locked by another all. I have 230GB free on this c:\ partition and I try to save to a desktop of my user. And I have an admin role. So none of these 3 reasons is right.

It's a fresh install on Windows 10 x64 logged in as a user belonging to the Administrators group. So really not sure why it would have any problems with the permissions... Could anyone from the Onlyoffice possibly assist?

I want to use Onlyoffice as it's a great alternative to the other main office-suite products that I find overpriced.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> It's a fresh install on Windows 10 x64 logged in as a user belonging
> to the Administrators group.

Do you have any AV software installed? If yes, please try saving the file with the antivirus disabled.